# Nginx proxy. Issue with CSP in case of HTTPS

Tags: nginx, content-security-policy, http-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, certbot

I am building a custom Nginx docker image able to automate transition to HTTPS. By the end of the **entrypoint.sh**, Here is what the conf looks like.

```
upstream some.domain.com{
    server wordpress:80;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name some.domain.com;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' ; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';img-src 'self' ; connect-src 'self' ; font-src 'self' fonts.g$
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://some.domain.com;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/some.domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/some.domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

This raises **CSP exceptions**. If I understand, this is because `self` is now `https://some.domain.com` and not `http://some.domain.com` anymore: (sorry, my browser speaks french)

```
Content Security Policy: Les paramètres de la page ont empêché le chargement d’une ressource à http://some.domain.com/wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=5.2.3 (« script-src »).
```

### Alternatives

How to deal with this issue? when I replace `http://some.domain.com` with `https://some.domain.com` in the *location* clause, I only get Errors 502 Bad Gateway. If I have to change something on the application side because of this change on the proxy, the latter does not look like a plug and play proxy anymore

My second thought was to get rid of `self` and explicitly allowing `http://some.domain.com` in the CSP but it does not feel right either. The point is, precisely, to make everything go through and HTTPS session.

Are redirect / rewrite clauses an option? Did cerbot do its job properly? Any insights are welcome

Comment: Can you try by replacing location block by this return 301 https://some.domain.com$request_uri;

Comment: with this, I end up with a strange recursion problem `http://some.domain.comhttp://some.domain.comhttp://some.domain.com`